# ¿Cómo evitar espacios, sino mostrar tabulaciones en código del IDE Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode

En el IDE Sublime Text se puede configurar para no mostrar estos espacios como puntos como se puede observar en la imagen en Visual Studio Code:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que en Sublime Text esos puntos se pueden convertir en tabulaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede configurar Visual Studio Code de esa misma manera?

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio code tiene una barra de información en la parte inferior derecha , está tiene una sección que te especificada si usas esapcios o tabulaciones y la cantidad de ellos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar click selecciona **Identación Usando Tabs** y después **Convertir Identación a Tabs**

Answer (score 2):

En el Status Bar puedes seleccionar el tipo de identacion, cambiala
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y selecciona 'Indent Using Tabs', luego escoge la cantidad de tabulaciones. En configuraciones puedes cambiar cuantos espacios son equivalentes una tabulacion. Pero con eso bastaria.

[image: Y selecciona 'Indent Using Tabs']

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esto necesitás entrar a la Configuración de vscode y buscar la opción `Render Whitespace`.

Solo existen estas 5 opciones que podés configurar. ¡Saludos!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]